# Finding if atleast one entry from a specified month string exists in Pandas datetime index

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a pandas dataframe `test_df` that looks like this:

```
                            reading                               
01-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  20.464020
02-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  22.440950
03-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  27.181500
04-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  25.318260
05-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  25.376050
06-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000   0.067112
07-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  19.313950
08-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  26.677340
09-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  26.801620
10-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  22.583950
11-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000   0.002765
12-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  26.496440
13-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  23.233720
14-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  23.956080
15-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  26.958120
16-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  27.351270
17-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  28.348710
18-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  25.494090
19-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  26.342880
20-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000  24.645530
```

The problem: given a string like '2016-01' a.k.a 'yyyy-mm', I want to find out if `any` entry from the specified month is present in the index of the  pandas dataframe `test_df`.

What I'm expecting is `True` for '2016-01' and `False` for any other string. Looking for the most concise method to do that.

### Problem setup:

To make things easy, this is the code to obtain test dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
temp_df = pd.read_json('{"reading":{"01-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":20.46402,"02-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":22.44095,"03-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":27.1815,"04-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":25.31826,"05-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":25.37605,"06-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":0.06711243,"07-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":19.31395,"08-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":26.67734,"09-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":26.80162,"10-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":22.58395,"11-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":0.002765084,"12-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":26.49644,"13-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":23.23372,"14-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":23.95608,"15-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":26.95812,"16-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":27.35127,"17-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":28.34871,"18-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":25.49409,"19-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":26.34288,"20-Jan-2016 00:00:00.000":24.64553}}')
```

I've tried:

```
>>'2016-01' in test_df.index
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use `DatetimeIndex` you can use [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_period.html) for convert to `PeriodIndex` and then [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) (thank you [John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909922/finding-if-atleast-one-entry-from-a-specified-month-string-exists-in-pandas-date#comment69032571_40910005) ):

```
print (temp_df.index.to_period('m'))
PeriodIndex(['2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01',
             '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01',
             '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01', '2016-01',
             '2016-01', '2016-01'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')

print (temp_df.index.to_period('m') == '2016-01')
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]

print ((temp_df.index.to_period('m') == '2016-01').any())
True
```

Comment: `to_period` is unnecessary here, `DatetimeIndex` supports partial datetime string matching see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing)

Comment: But why different output? Why you get no all True?

Comment: It seems no support it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is a bug will investigate

Comment: It ssems convert `2016-01` to day and year, what is wrong.

Comment: Simpler is `temp_df.index.to_period('m') == '2016-01'` which also works.  OP didn't say there was a list of periods to look for, just one.

Comment: It looks like if you pass even `2016` to `isin` it's up-converting this to a full datetime object with default attributes so it becomes `2016-01-01` so only the first entry is `True`, it's unclear if this is expected or not

Comment: Even `temp_df.index.strftime('%Y-%m') == '2016-01'` FYI just does the job.

Comment: @NickilMaveli: That's not efficient.